# Replace a column of numbers with the associated label from another text file using the index on the text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to loop through column of numbers and replace a with the associated label from another text file using the index on the text file. But it keeps returning an error

```
#conditions.txt has the labels while 'Reason for absence' has the numbers

with open('conditions.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
ds = pd.DataFrame(lines)
index=ds.index
print(index)

newname=df['Reason for absence'].copy()

for value in newname:
    for i in index:
        if value in newname == index :
            newname=ds
```

Comment: please provide the error message

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to another posted question. While the approaches are different, possibly you are looking for the same end result. Take a look at the provided solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74492306/how-to-insert-a-pandas-series-as-a-new-column-in-dataframe-matching-with-the-in/74499345#74499345). If the solution is not helpful, request you provide the error message.